# Calcular valores en input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, input

**Hola a todos.**

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Tengo una dificultad que me ha llevado varios días fastidiando y no he podido resolver

[image: script suma inputs]

Tengo estos **3 inputs** que deben sumarse en la **linea de resultado**. Me funciona cuando digito los valores en cada caja de texto. Pero cuando le doy clic sobre los botones de *"+"* y *"-"*. Cambia el valor en el **input**, pero no me los suma en el resultado.

Este es el código con el cual estoy realizando este programa

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <form id="formulario">
          <div class="decrease value-button" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="placeOrder" />
          <input class="number" type="number" id="number" name="number" value="0" />
          <div class="increase value-button" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
        </form>
      </li>
      <li>
        <form id="formulario">
          <div class="decrease value-button" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="placeOrder" />
          <input class="number" type="number" id="number" name="number" value="0" />
          <div class="increase value-button" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
        </form>
      </li>
      <li>
        <form id="formulario" name="form">
          <div class="decrease value-button" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="placeOrder" />
          <input class="number" type="number" id="number" name="number" value="0" />
          <div class="increase value-button" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>

  <div><span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span></div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('div#increase').on('click', function () {
  var $qty = $(this).closest('#formulario').find('input#number');
  var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
  }

});

$('div#decrease').on('click', function () { 
  var $qty = $(this).closest('#formulario').find('input#number');
  var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
  }

});

function sumar() {
  var total = 0;

  $(".number").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
    
  });
  
  $('#spTotal').html(total)
}

  $('.number').on('keyup', function() {
    sumar();
  })
```

El código CSS no lo veo necesario. Pero si necesitan reproducir el programa, lo tengo colgado en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jonedi/pen/mdxgYmL)

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan proporcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo que me percaté es que cuando estás entrando a la función de incrementar y decrementar, nunca estás haciendo el llamado a la función sumar, por la cual no estás sumando nada. La solución sería que al final llames a dicha función:

```
$('div#increase').on('click', function () {
  var $qty = $(this).closest('#formulario').find('input#number');
  var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
  }
  return sumar();
});

$('div#decrease').on('click', function () { 
  var $qty = $(this).closest('#formulario').find('input#number');
  var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
  }
  return sumar();
});
```

Comment: gracias @Cris223511.dev. Me funcionó perfecto tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que al momento de apretar el boton de mas o menos, cambia el valor, pero nunca lo suma, lo que se me ocurre que debes hacer es, luego de cambiar el valor del input, llamar a la funcion que hace la suma o la resta

```js
$('div#increase').on('click', function () {
  var $qty = $(this).closest('#formulario').find('input#number');
  var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
    sumar();
  }

});

$('div#decrease').on('click', function () { 
  var $qty = $(this).closest('#formulario').find('input#number');
  var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
    sumar();
  }

});
```

Comment: Gracias Braian. Si creo que me puede funcionar esa solución, voy a probar colocándole un parámetro a la función, para que me funcione. Gracias por la colaboración